# Easier way to invert data from list of character vectors?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks something like this:

```
  states       responsible
1     KS        Joe, Suzie
2     MO               Bob
3     CO Suzie, Bob, Ralph
4     NE               Joe
5     MT      Suzie, Ralph
```

Where each state has a list of people responsible for it in another column. I'd like to invert this to create a list of all the states that each person is responsible for. 
Here's how to create a reproducible example:

```
states <- c("KS", "MO", "CO", "NE", "MT")
responsible <- list(c("Joe", "Suzie"), "Bob", c("Suzie", "Bob", "Ralph"), "Joe", c("Suzie", "Ralph"))    
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(states, responsible))
```

Here's how I would like the data to look:

```
  person       states
1     Joe           KS, NE
2     Suzie     KS, CO, MT
3     Bob           MO, CO
4     Ralph         CO, MT
```

I have used the following to get what I want, but I feel that I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be. using `melt` and `split` get me almost what I want, but I take a few more steps to then convert from indices back to the values. Here's the ugly solution:

```
people <- unique(unlist(df$responsible))

foo <- melt(responsible)

bar <- split(foo$L1, foo$value)

#This function just grabs the indices from 'bar' and gets the corresponding states. 
#Really ugly and I'm guessing unnecessary.
stackoverflow_function <- function(person) {
  return(states[do.call('$', list(bar, paste0(person)))])
}

answer <- lapply(people, stackoverflow_function)

as.data.frame(cbind(people, answer))
```

Any help is appreciated. It feels like I'm overlooking something simple.

Comment: It might be more convenient to have your data in a format like `dat = data.frame(state = rep(unlist(df$states), lengths(df$responsible)), resp = unlist(df$responsible))`. Then you could, e.g. use `aggregate(as.character(state) ~ resp, dat, c)` etc.

Comment: @alexis_laz, Thank you for pointing this out. I was able to convert my data like so:

    `foo$state <- states[foo$L1]`

and then aggregate

    `aggregate(as.character(state) ~ value, foo, c)`

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table`:

```
data.table::setDT(df)
df[, .(responsible = unlist(responsible)), .(states = unlist(states))]
  [, .(states = list(states)), .(responsible)]

   responsible   states
1:         Joe    KS,NE
2:       Suzie KS,CO,MT
3:         Bob    MO,CO
4:       Ralph    CO,MT
```